# Remove curly brackets from JObject

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I receive a text which I parse as a JObject

```
txt = {"welcome":["Hello friend."],"image":"Y","IDs":{}}
var object = JObject.Parse(txt);
```

Among the values inside there is one called IDs which sometimes is empty.
I get the value by

```
var mainID = object["IDs"].ToString();
```

And then I insert the value in a table.
The problem is that when the value is empty it return with {}.
So the insert statement fails.
How can I remove the curly brackets when the value is empty?

Comment: Please, share your json

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski added the json in text format. As above I parse it to get the IDs object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update based on comment**

You could use the following

```
var mainID = (jobj["IDs"] is JValue)?(string)jobj["IDs"]:defaultValue;
```

Comment: I get always the default value for some reason. Either getting txt = {"welcome":["Hello friend."],"image":"Y","IDs":{}} or txt = {"welcome":["Hello friend."],"image":"Y","IDs":"23"}  it returns the default value